# Delete unique rows in Excel file

Tags: sql-server, excel, unique, rows

I've been asked quite a strange thing, even though I guess it's very simple.
Eliminate unique rows from an Excel file and just leave duplicates in.
Is there a simple way to do that ?
All the options are very welcome, e.g. loading excel file into Sql-Server and apply a select on that!!!
Thks a lot in advance
M.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this sql query return only dublicate rows

```
select column1, column2, column3, ...
from Table1
group by column1, column2, column3, ...
having count(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming data in A2 to A11, enter this in B2 and copy down:

```
=COUNTIF($A$2:$A$11,A2)=1
```

[image]

Then filter column B to TRUE and delete those rows.

Comment: Can do the same thing in place, without the helper column. Use conditional format, Highlight Duplicates.

Comment: @user2140261, note that this requires Excel 2007 or later. At any rate, I like helper columns, unless there's some reason not to use them.